# Selecting a number of strings from a vector and passing it to a second vector to display?

Tags: c++, class, vector

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
class BoxOfProduce
{
    private:
        vector<string>Produce={"Apples", "Peas","Lemons", "Tomatoes","Peaches","Garlic"};
        vector <string>box;//vector to hold the 4 strings
    public:
        BoxOfProduce(){}//default constructor

        void print()
        {
            for (auto& s : Produce) //displays all strings in vector
            {
                cout << s << " ";
            }
            cout<<endl;

        }
};

int main()
{
    BoxOfProduce Box;
    Box.print();//print function
}
```

Currently trying to figure out a way to pull four random strings from Produce to box. How can I randomize Produce and then send the strings to box?

Comment: If you do not want duplicates, use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle and pick the first n strings.

Comment: @user4581301, duplicates don't matter.

Comment: In that case, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution and have it generate numbers [0, `vector.size()`). Get four numbers and use them as the indices of the values you want from the `vector`.

Comment: Warning: If  compiling with mingw, `random_device` is broken, so seed the generator with the current time.

Comment: I've searched and tried random device, it didn't work.

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a useful problem description. Do you think that if you told your mechanic "my car doesn't move", he'll know what the problem is?

Comment: I mean, if it's supposed to work then I'm most likely not implementing it correctly. I can't say because I haven't found any clear ways to deal with classes and vectors.

Comment: The pages I linked to have excellent examples of how to use the classes and functions they discuss. Use the examples as the basis for your attempts, then ask questions about the attempts if needed. The important part is to make a credible attempt. We can help you fix a good attempt. We can't help you fix nothing.